# Save Outlook attachments to SharePoint to be processed by accounts

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, email, attachments, workflow-manager

I have been playing around for a couple days, but keep coming stuck and hope someone can advise me.

As a finance manager I want emails from suppliers with attachments to be processed via a flow:

1. Attachments from suppliers to be saved to SP (only the invoice and not the email images)
2. I then want to assign the invoice to the responsible 'Manager' for him to allocate the cost center (status update triggers an email to manager in question)
3. Response from manager updates the 'Cost Centre' column
4. Bank assistant then pays the invoice and updates the 'Status' to PAID

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you added an email address to the library so it will take incoming email? Once you do that - you have to create the workflow in Designer. What version are you using? I found this if you have access to FLOW - https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/f7a46809e53c42108034e56acf83bb79/save-my-email-attachments-to-a-sharepoint-document-library/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm working with SP 2013.

I am able to save attachments to my Library. But now I would like columns called Manager, Cost Centre, and Status added that when I enter the managers name he gets an email to update the file column. I can add these columns, but I am unable to create flows to update them (Library columns) in flow, it seems as though Library flows pertain more to updating the file itself, and I need to combine the Library with a List to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

So you have to add those columns and build a workflow that says when Manager is not blank/or not empty - the workflow will start and sent the email.  You need to make sure the box for the workflow conditions for a change is checked.  You can do a workflow on a library.  Give me a few minutes to make an example and I will post the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

What your workflow should look like - Choose If Current Item equals value.

[image: workflow screen]

Be sure to edit your start properties to be on creation.

[image: Start options]